# Project not under version control - Imported from EGit repo

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I've cloned a (remote) repo into Eclipse(EGit), which created a working directory for the contents. When I imported this working directory as a General Project into Eclipse workspace, the project is not under version control (none of the files have decorators and the rt-click on project has Team -> Share Project).

The question is, why isnt the imported 'General Project' not under version control and how to get it under version control.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer myself. Importing the working directory through File -> Import -> Git -> Projects from Git route, does add the project to workspace. But it doesnt add the project to version control.

But, rt-clk on Working Directory from the Git Repositories view, and Import Projects... as a General Project adds the project to Workspace AND puts it under that repository's version management.

Hope it helps someone.